# Error saying http method is not supported in my route

Tags: php, laravel, http, post, get

I'm fairly new to programming and this is my first question in stackoverflow so I apologize if my formatting is incorrect. I'm trying to make my first crud website and I want to update an item's database, tagging it as 'borrowed'. But I'm receiving this error when using my anchor button:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.

**index.blade:**

```
@foreach ($histories as $history)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $history->user->username }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $history->user->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $history->game->title }}</td>

                            <td>
                                @csrf
                                @method("PUT")
                                <a href='{{ url("/pending/$history->id/returned") }}' class="btn-group btn-block">Tag as Returned</a>
                            </td>
```

**route:**

```
Route::put('/pending/{id}/returned', 'PendingController@isReturned');
```

**controller:**

```
public function isReturned($id)
    {
        $history = History::find($id);

        $history->is_returned = 1;
        $history->save();

        return redirect('pending/adminindex');
    }
```

I've tried making the button into a form with a button instead but with the same error.

```
<td>
    <form action='{{ url("/pending/$history->id/returned") }}' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="btn-group btn-block">
      @csrf
      @method("PUT")
      <button type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-info">Tag as Returned</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Comment: Hello. I've tried your suggestion but I'm receiving a new error: The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Answer (score 0):

The only problem was that `$history->id` was sent as a plain text as it is.

**Solution 1**: You better add a `name` to your route, for ex. `pending.return`.

```
Route::put('/pending/{id}/returned', 'PendingController@isReturned')->name('pending.return');
```

And your form, you can use now a `route name` instead of `url`.

```
<form action='{{ route("pending.return", $history->id) }}' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="btn-group btn-block">
```

---

Or **Solution 2** you can stick with `url` just change it to:

```
<form action='{{ url("/pending/". $history->id ."/returned") }}' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="btn-group btn-block">
```